# OpenCV 2.1 Strange Errors

Tags: opencv

I'm not sure if this is the right place for asking these kind of question but I have no better place in mind.

After LOTS of coding in OpenCV, I'm trying to migrate to new C++ interface of openCV which has been introduced in OpenCV 2.0. but I keep getting strange errors.

For example:

- trying to use pre-built dlls and libs, I got exceptions in "cv::warpAffine" and "findContours" cv::function at runtime. I compiled the openCV, used my own build of libs and dlls and everything got fixed!

  the same problem happened in linux.

  linking the "Debug" built dlls with "Release" built of program cause some unexpected runtime errors, and vice versa.

and some other errors.
can anyone helping me with what I'm doing wrong? (please keep in mind that I coded alot with older version of openCV).

Comment: I've had those errors too. In fact, one of the errors I encountered was because one particular parameters was optional in the C interface, but not in the C++ interface. Weird it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I migrated to C++ interface I couldnt make openCV work until I compiled the source by myself. Probably DLL's and Libs that are installed with opencv are good only to a specific machine.

Another thing. Try to do the following if you use Visual Studio
go to Project Properties->Click the C/C++ folder->Code Generation->Runtime Library and change it to /MDd  in Debug configuration and /MD in release

It solves a problem with esceptions related to STL

Answer (score 0):

Some of the functions ave moved out to new libs (especially some of the stereo functions are in calib3d) and the header file structure is completely changed in 2.2

There are some [guides to the configuration](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide)  eg for [visual studio](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++)